# Question about java concurrenthashmap replace method 

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I have the following code

```
public class Test{

private static final String key = "key";

public static void main(String[] a){
    ConcurrentHashMap<String,String > map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
    System.out.println(map.replace(key,"1"));
    System.out.println(map.replace(key,"2"));
}

}
```

The output is null both times. Isn't it supposed to be 1 second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says:

> Replace entry for key only if
>   currently mapped to some value. Acts
>   as
>
> ```
> if ((map.containsKey(key)) 
>     return map.put(key, value);   
> else
>     return null;
> ```

Hence no, the first replace doesn't do the put.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought I could avoid a put. It wont let me accept the answer until 7 minutes or something :)

Answer (score 4):

From [the reference:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> replace(K key, V value)
>
> Replace entry 
>   for key only if currently mapped to some value.

Since it starts as null, it won't replace the entry at that key- so it won't create an entry for it.

You can also see in that link that the method simply skips to return null if map.containsKey(key) is false, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc:

> Replaces the entry for a key only if currently mapped to a given value.

`null` IS expected both times because there was never a mapping for `key`.